# Tab leader not showing for long headings in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word, table-of-contents, microsoft-word-2016

I am using Table of Content (TOC) to automatically put headings into a TOC. The tab leaders are the dots between heading and page number. When the headings are longer than 1 line, the tab leaders are missing. Can I ask how to solve this?

[image]

**After changing the "Hanging" value for the TOC:**

**- Problem 1:**

[image]

**- Problem 2:**

[image]

---

Reply to Luke:
Either move right or left will change the indent for all the Level 2 Heading.

- If move right, Heading 1.2 becomes fine but Heading 1.1 becomes
  wrong
- If move left, the Level 2 Heading becomes more left than the Level 1 Heading, which is not good.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add a few words to this long heading and refresh TOC? Will this "solve" the problem or will page number still be placed just after the last word? If this "solves" the problem then you may have a tab stop in this line (or maybe in style definition for this TOC level).

Comment: @endrju yes, it solved the problem! But how can I remove the "tab stop"?

Comment: Now I can see that "29" page number in 1.2 is aligned to the same position as "Introduction" "The" and "The" in upper lines, so tab stop is useful here. So instead of removing it go to Line Spacing Options for this line and in Special set Hanging to the position of where "formulation" ends. (I don't have Word 2016 so there may be some differences here from Word 2010)

Comment: @endrju  do you mean put cursor in the heading in the TOC or in the content? If I put cursor in the content, then choose "Hanging", the problem in the TOC still exist no matter what value I set for the "By".

Comment: I mean: in the heading in the TOC.

Comment: @endrju  it worked for that heading. However, two other problems: 1) all the Heading 2 are hanging more left than Heading 1; 2) the "Tab leader not showing" problem appears for "2.2 Methods"

Comment: You should edit style Heading 2 to fix this. Make a backup. Then Alt+Ctrl+S, choose Heading 2, modify. Then in the window that pops up: for problem 1: In Format change Paragraph settings (increase left indent). For problem 2: In Format change tabulators: remove tab stop at position near "88" page number in the TOC.

Comment: @endrju  " Alt+Ctrl+S" only split the window or remove the split. Sorry, I become confused. If I change style, it only changes the heading in the content, not in the TOC.

Comment: OK, this shortcut works for me in Word 2010 (Polish), try: Alt+Ctrl+Shift+S. My mistake about style name: change not "Heading 2" but "TOC 2" (probably this is the name in English version).

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same issue- however, my issue occurred with both heading that were too short (no leader- so the page number would appear directly beside the heading), or a long heading wrapped to a new line and the same would happen.

You can fix the issue by:

1. enable the Ruler in your document (under the View tab on the ribbon menu).
2. select line/heading in your TOC, and you will see a short bolded L shape appear in the Ruler (saying Left Tab when you hover on it)
3. re-position the marker to the left so all words (even short TOC entries) clear it.

I hope that helps!

Comment: What do you mean "re-position the marker so it is in-line with the end of the heading", could you see my updated screenshot?

Comment: 1. Select the TOC that has no dot leader lines with the short entries. 
2. View the ruler. 
3. If there is a tab sign more to the right than the shortest entry, _drag_ it leftwards, so it is more left than the length of the shortest word. The dot leader lines now also appear for the shortest entries.
Actually the original entry's wording is even more clear, but maybe it helps someone. This trick does work, and is far easier than whole complicated discussions elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but found the conversation here confusing, it still took me a long time to figure out the solution. I'll therefore try to sum it up.

I have MS Word 2010.

Let's stick to the Original Poster's first screenshot, where the second line in the second-level table-of-content ("TOC") heading is not indented and the page number is not right-aligned. In my understanding, the solution is to set the indentation of a second-level TOC-heading to "Hanging" and set the hanging value equal to physical length of the string "1.2\tab". The indentation then somehow forces the page number to jump off to the right margin where it belongs. Obviously, this has to be done for each heading level separately since e.g. a fourth-level heading "1.1.1.1.\tab" will have a greater physical length.

Step by step:

1. go to ribbon "References", click "TOC" and then "Insert TOC" at the bottom
2. in the opened dialogue box, hit "Modify"
3. in the next open dialogue box, select the desired TOC level, and hit "Modify"
4. in the new dialogue box, click the "Format" drop-down menu at the bottom, and select "Paragraph"
5. finally, in this new dialog box see the "Indentation" section, and in the "Special" drop-down select "Hanging" and insert the appropriate value in the "By" field. You'll have to find the optimal value by experimenting, my guess is it will most often be 1 - 2 cm.
6. close (hit "OK") in all the open dialog boxes and at the end, when You're asked whether to replace the existing TOC with a new one, click "Yes".

I don't guarantee this is 100% correct but so far, it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

My admin lady literally hit tab and shifted the page number to the right. The leader then appeared. Try hitting tab.